# Hello, how do I run my information over the tor network twice

Tags: relays, exit-relays, circuit

I was wondering how do I send my data through the tor circuit twice (6 relays instead of the normal 3) if that would add extra security so I can be fully untraceable?

Comment: Tor team says that 3 hops is enough for anonymity, for making more secure you should use IPs of countries that don't have laws for data retention on ISP/Data Centers.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot route your traffic over the Tor network twice since relays [will not allow](https://gitlab.torproject.org/tpo/core/tor/-/issues/2667) new circuits originating from exit relays.

It's not recommended to use longer-length circuits. The standard circuit length of 3 has been chosen since having more than 3 doesn't provide a significant benefit for the extra load it puts on the Tor network. It could potentially make you *more* identifiable since your traffic may look significantly different from other users (for example your latency will be twice as long on average).

If you really wanted to use longer-length circuits, I can think of two options:

1. Increase `DEFAULT_ROUTE_LEN` in tor's source code. This option isn't really meant to be changed, so it's likely something will break.
2. Use tor's control port to build longer-length circuits. For example with stem, you could use [`controller.extend_circuit()`](https://stem.torproject.org/api/control.html#stem.control.Controller.extend_circuit). You will have to write your own script to do this.

> so I can be fully untraceable?

You will never be fully untraceable, so I wouldn't worry about that.